Kafka event driven or polling based
I want to understand whether overall Kafka structure is considered event driven or both event driven + polling based.
When messages are recieved in kafka brokers does it send event to consumers or does the consumers keep polling for messages. if consumers keep polling then how is it a event driven architecture and if event is triggered by kafka broker to consumers then how do consumers have polling properties "MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG" (indicating polling interval periods), "MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG" (indicating max records to be picked in poll)

Consumers can be configured to constantly poll in a loop.
Since the "overall Kafka structure" includes the clients, your processing logic would be event driven, after the records had been polled.

"Consumers can be configured to constantly poll in a loop"
Is there a way to process messages in realtime instead of consumers polling for them?

Consumers must always poll. A well optimized consumer can process hundreds of messages a second from a partition. There's network transfer involved and deserialization before processing, so it's not clear what you want by "real time"
